# Force Macs to run Xprotect updater through terminal to get latest NTPD security patch

Tags: macos, terminal, security, software-update

Apple released the the patch for an NTPD hole.  This patch is automatically updated if you have SystemPreferences-->App Store-->Install system data files and security updates; checked. Which we don't.

You used to be able to run in terminal the command:

```
/usr/libexec/XProtectUpdater
```

this would force a check for updates to xprotect.

It seems this command no longer exist in 10.9 and above, is there any other way to force a mac to run the data files and security updates through terminal?  Otherwise a solution to turn on just the check box for "Install system data files and security updates" and leave the rest uncheck.

[Apple NTPD patch](http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT6601)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check out this post at [macops.ca](http://macops.ca/os-x-admins-your-clients-are-not-getting-background-security-updates/).

Using:

```
/usr/bin/sudo softwareupdate --background-critical
```

seems to be the answer.

Comment: sudo softwareupdate --background-critical  worked prefect.  Does what the old xprotect command did.  Wonder why its not documented in softwareupdate --help